# Retrieve data from array without key in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a php array and I want to get the values from the array without getting the key.
For example

```
$array = array($val);// $val = data comes from excel sheet  
print_r($array); //the out put which I get is - Array ( [0] => 123-456-789-abcdef/ )
```

I want to get only the values such as 123-456-789-abcdef.
Purpose of getting only the value is to save in the mysql database.

Can some help me out?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the PHP manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php. Although it seems you _already_ have an indexed array.

Comment: You should spend five minutes and [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

Comment: Question should be useful to the beginners of PHP. This site is not only using by genius. Each and every person who is doing developing searching on this site when they got a trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, since your array key is "0", you can access the paired value via

```
$array[0]
```

Or more generally,

```
$the_value = $the_array[$the_key];
```